# How to get the address of a JITed code in C#?

Tags: c#, jit

I have 2 questions.

One is to check if a function has been JITed in C# ?

The other one is, how to get the address of the JITed function ?

In C# we have the code below.

```
RuntimeHelpers.PrepareMethod(MethodTarget.MethodHandle);
AddrTarget = MethodTarget.MethodHandle.GetFunctionPointer();
```

I know the `RuntimeHelpers.PrepareMethod` method could make the method *JITed*. However, if the JIT was not invoked in my code, how to check if the method has been JITed and how to get the address of that ?

Comment: I would exactly expect `MethodHandle.GetFunctionPointer()` to return the address of the JIT-compiled code, null if it hasn't been rendered. Is that not what you see?

Comment: Take System.WebClient.DownloadString(string) for example, I can get a JITed address for this method with windbg, by retrieving the exact symbol name. And I can still get another address by MethodHandle.GetFunctionPointer(), could you give me some clues about that, why the same method has 2 different JITed addresses ? I use .net framework 3.5, version  2.0.50727.1433

Comment: It might have moved in memory.  I don't know about pointers to functions, but pointers to objects can become invalid if the objects aren't pinned in memory.  It might work the same for functions.